# How to construct a CU3 gate using only CX and U3 gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, universal-gates

Knowing that CX and U3 (taking 3 parameters $\theta, \phi$ and $\lambda$) form a set of universal gates how can I construct an arbitrary CU3 gate using a decomposition of only CX and arbitrary U3 gates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the ideas from [these slides](https://qudev.phys.ethz.ch/static/content/courses/QSIT07/presentations/Schmassmann.pdf), specifically slide 8,9,10.

We can decompose any $U_{3}(\theta,\phi,\lambda)$ into a rotation around the $Z,Y$ & again $Z$ axis, because for any $U \in SU(2)$ we can write:
\begin{equation}
U = 
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{i(\alpha-\frac{\beta}{2}-\frac{\delta}{2})}\cos(\frac{\gamma}{2})
&
e^{i(\alpha-\frac{\beta}{2}+\frac{\delta}{2})}\sin(\frac{\gamma}{2})
\\
e^{i(\alpha+\frac{\beta}{2}-\frac{\delta}{2})}\sin(\frac{\gamma}{2})
&
e^{i(\alpha+\frac{\beta}{2}+\frac{\delta}{2})}\cos(\frac{\gamma}{2})
\end{bmatrix}
= e^{i\alpha}R_{z}(\beta)R_{y}(\gamma)R_{z}(\delta),
\end{equation}

where $\beta$, $\gamma$ & $\delta$ can be computed straightforwardly from $\theta$, $\phi$ and $\lambda$.

Then, let $A = R_{z}(\beta)R_{y}(\gamma/2)$, $B = R_{y}(-\gamma/2)R_{z}(-\delta/2-\beta/2)$ and $C = R_{z}(\delta/2 - \beta/2)$.

A straightforward calculation shows that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
ABC &= R_{z}(\beta)R_{y}(\gamma/2)R_{y}(-\gamma/2)R_{z}(-\delta/2-\beta/2)R_{z}(\delta/2 - \beta/2) = I\\
AXBXC &= R_{z}(\beta)R_{y}(\gamma/2)XR_{y}(-\gamma/2)R_{z}(-\delta/2-\beta/2)XR_{z}(\delta/2 - \beta/2) \\
&= R_{z}(\beta)R_{y}(\gamma/2)R_{y}(\gamma/2)XXR_{z}(\delta/2+\beta/2)R_{z}(\delta/2 - \beta/2) \\
&= R_{z}(\beta)R_{y}(\gamma)R_{z}(\delta) = e^{-i\alpha}U.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We can use this fact to implement $CU$ by using two $CX$ gates that we apply between the $A$&$B$ and the $B$&$C$ gates:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&(I\otimes A)CX(I\otimes B)CX(I\otimes C) \\
= &\big(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes ABC\big) + \big(|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes AXBXC\big) \\
= &\big(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I\big) + \big(|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes e^{-i\alpha}U\big) \\
= & CU \big(R_{z}(\alpha)\otimes I\big)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the last phase gate on the control qubit is needed because we have the phase $\alpha$ in our equality $U = e^{i\alpha}AXBXC$.

This allows us to implement any controlled-$U$ gate.

Comment: If you need help with calculating $\big(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta\big)$ from $\big(\theta, \phi, \lambda\big)$ please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a construction of $CU3$ gate on IBM Q:

```
  u1((lambda+phi)/2) c;
  u1((lambda-phi)/2) t;
  cx c,t;
  u3(-theta/2,0,-(phi+lambda)/2) t;
  cx c,t;
  u3(theta/2,phi,0) t;
```

Where `t` is a target qubit and `c` is control qubit.

Note that $U1$ gate is a special case of $U3$, it holds that $U1(\lambda)=U3(0,0,\lambda)$.